# SQL Query in C# Program

Tags: sql

Is it possible to make an `where var1!=var2` ? because when I try the compiler said it"s an invalid operator . (i also tried `NOT IS`).

The full Error-Message:

```
Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression
        'emp_course.e_id!=employee.e_id'
```

Comment: What *database* product? oracle? Please include that `SQL` statement in your post.

Comment: the sql with full explanation is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755676/sql-query-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
where var1 <> var2
```

TSQL allows both `!=` and `<>`, whereas other dialects have different rules.

Comment: yeah I also tried this this will not throw an error but it seams not to work ... maybe i have a mess in the other part of my sql query ...

Comment: Possibly - if you are having trouble with it create a new question and post the link in the comments here, and I'll have a look :)

Comment: thanks so much :) i just have to wait another 14min to post it because i'm a newbie here ;)

Comment: so here it is :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755676/sql-query-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

As the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) sais it should be `expression < > expression`