# SQL Query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, join

I might have a problem with my SQL query. In this query I'm combining 4 different tables.

- I have a table `courses` where general information is stored (`course_number`, `course_title`).
- I have a table `employees` where general information of employees isstored (`empname`, and a `job_id`).
- A employee has a job. A employee needs to take courses. It depends on the job which courses he has to take. This info is stored in the table `job_course` (with the `job_id` and the `course_id`).
- If a employee completed a course it is stored in the table `emp_courses` (with the `e_id` and the `course_id`)

Now I want to search a certain course - when the user presses the search button he should get two different results.

- The first one: here you can see **which employee already took this course** (this query works so far)
- the second one: here you can see **which employee still needs to take the course**. So i need to check which job the employee has and if he needs to make that course . and also i just want to have the ones that are not completed yet. 
  And that's the query that is not working

Here it is:

```
OpenDb_Open("select course_number,course_title, empname from course 
INNER JOIN (job_course INNER JOIN (employee INNER JOIN emp_course  
ON emp_course.e_id<>employee.e_id) ON job_course.job_id=employee.job_id) 
ON course.course_id=job_course.course_id 
where course_number like '" + coursenumber + "'");
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query in C# Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755326/sql-query-in-c-sharp-program)

Comment: *shudder* - don't concatenate input like that; **please** use `where course_number like @coursenumber` and add a parameter called `@coursenumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courses the employee hasn't taken.

```
SELECT * FROM courses
WHERE course_number IN (
    SELECT course_id FROM job_course
    WHERE course_id NOT IN (
        SELECT course_id FROM emp_courses
        WHERE emp_id = {someid}
    ) AND job_id = (
        SELECT job_id FROM employees
        WHERE emp_id = {user_input}
    )
)
```

Which employees still need to take a course.

```
SELECT emp_name FROM employees
WHERE emp_id NOT IN (
    SELECT emp_id FROM emp_courses
    WHERE course_id = {user_input}
)
```

Variant of above.

```
SELECT emp_name FROM employees
WHERE emp_id NOT IN (
    SELECT emp_id FROM emp_courses
    WHERE course_id = (
        SELECT course_id FROM courses
        WHERE course_number = {user_input}
    )
)
```

Comment: what do you mean with the "someid" ... in your query i don't have the possibility to compare the stored course_numbers to the one that the users types in .. ( I should have mentioned that : The user has the possibility to type in the cours_number and when he presses the search button, it will be stored : string coursenumber=this.textBox1.Text; )

Comment: So the value that's typed in goes in the place of that. I couldn't put anything there because it has to be supplied. There are many different ways to query your database from a lot of different angles but I think the second query is exactly what you're looking for. Plug the users input in there and get the employees that haven't taken that specific course.

Comment: oh but the course_id is not the course_number .. so i also need the course table... but besides that your query looks good !

Comment: @meilenea If this answered it please mark it as the answer by clicking the check box just below the voting system. Thanks!

Comment: Oh thanks for the last one ! no i just need to make on mor comparision ... but i think i can make it on my own ;)